# how can i use log4j in grails application?

Tags: grails, log4j

how can i use log4j in grails application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the Logging section of the [manual](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.1.x/guide/3.%20Configuration.html).
log4j is built in and has a basic configuration out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You could use log4j right from the box, for example:

```
log.debug "The value of foo is $foo"
```

[Configuration of logging in last version](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.2%20Logging)

If you are into unit testing be sure to check mockLogging method in Testing section.